# Vim: Close 1 file in a split view?

Tags: vim, split, window

I'm currently learning vim using vimtutor but whenever I try to open vimtutor there's always a split screen view of the previous file like this:

[image]

How can I close the bottom window?

Comment: Try `:on` and let us know which window get closed?

Answer (score 1):

You can press 'Ctrl w w' to switch between the window panes. Switch to the second window pane and in normal mode, type :q and enter. This should close the bottom window.

Comment: :q ended up closing the whole vim editor instead... althought it seems :close seems to have worked. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. It does seem like a split open window so this is what normally works. Are you opening vimtutor straight from the cmd line or from inside vim ? From what I remember, you can open vimtutor by simply typing that into your cmd line.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot looks like an empty file on the bottom; and on the top, the vim help screen describing vimtutor.  I think you must have typed `vim` on the command line (which launched Vim with an empty file), then `:help vimtutor` (which brings up a Vim help page about vimtutor).

That would be why `ctrl-w w` and `:q` closed the whole vim editor.  The `ctrl-w w` put you back in the new blank file; and `:q` executed a "quit" command.

Instead of launching vim that way, on the command line try typing `vimtutor`.

Answer (score 1):

The top window has file type of "help" (this is shown in its status line). Help is normally viewed in splits, not as a single window. When other window is closed with `:q` and "help" becomes the last one, vim closes the whole tab or even the app. So don't do this.

If you seem the window is too small then maximize it vertically by pressing ctrl-w followed by "underscore". But it is really a matter of habit. No one bothers doing `tab help vimtutor` or such. Split view is just okay. So the best advice for you is "to comply".

Answer (score 1):

You are not "using vimtutor"; you are using Vim and viewing the help for vimtutor.

What you get is absolutely normal and expected: the help is always displayed in a window so that you still have the thing you are working on visible while you check the documentation.

To actually *use* vimtutor, quit Vim and, when you are back at your shell, run the following command:

```
$ vimtutor
```

Comment: Upvoted. Other answers only answer the question, but this addresses the underlying problem

Answer (score 1):

To keep only the current window press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>. Mnemonic "only"